# data written to txt file appears in some bizzare language[C]

Tags: c, file, struct, file-writing

So I've written a program that will take in a information about a dvd *(specifically it's **postion**, **IDkey**(just some random number) **Title**, **Genre** and **Year of release**)*, and using a struct it will write that info to a .txt file called *"person.txt"*. I'm positive my code works for the most part but when I go to test it the output received in the .txt file is written in some weird symbol language and not English and quite frankly I have no idea as to why this is. Any explanation on why this is happening would be much appreciated, thanks :)

**PROGRAM**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// a struct to read and write
struct dvd
{
    int fposition;
    int fIdKey;
    char ftitle[50];
    char fgenre[50];
    int fyear;
};

int main ()
{
    FILE *outfile;
    struct dvd input;

    // open file for writing
    outfile = fopen ("person.txt", "w");
    if (outfile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opend file\n");
        exit (1);
    }


    printf("Postion: ");
    scanf("%d", &input.fposition);

    printf("ID Key: ");
    scanf("%d", &input.fIdKey);

    printf("Title: ");
    scanf("%s",&input.ftitle);

    printf("Genre: ");
    scanf("%s", &input.fgenre);

    printf("Year: ");
    scanf("%d", &input.fyear);

    // write struct to file
    fwrite (&input, sizeof(struct dvd), 1, outfile);

    if(fwrite != 0)
        printf("contents to file written successfully !\n");
    else
        printf("error writing file !\n");

    // close file
    fclose (outfile);

    return 0;
}
```

**TEST RUN**
[image]

**TEST RUN OUTPUT IN THE .TXT FILE**
[image]

Comment: What *exactly* do you expect to be in the output file? Do you understand you're writing a raw binary (in-memory representation) structure directly to the file, and not serializing it in any way?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Well I'm trying to just write the data as it is entered by the user(the IdKey, title, etc) and what do you mean exactly by specializing it?

Comment: It's been 20-some years since I touched C, but it looks like the garbage you are seeing is just the content of your char arrays after the last user input for each field. Given that you haven't overwritten it, it is in fact contained in the character array and thus written by fwrite. i.e. if you allow for 50 characters and user inputs "a" (without quotes) then it should write a + 49 characters of garbage (maybe minus 1-2 characters to account for string terminator \0 but take this with a grain of salt).

Comment: Sorry, I meant "serializing" (damn autocorrect).

Comment: @ApplePie I declared it as 50 characters as a sort of precaution because I wouldn't exactly know the length of the title or genre entered by the user, but if that is what's causing the issue here I'll have a look at it and try working something out

Comment: Not related to your issue, but `if(fwrite != 0)` is always true because you're comparing a function pointer. If you want to check the result of `fwrite` you need to capture and use the return value from when you call it.

Comment: @Uzair it's not an issue per se. It's just that C is doing exactly what you are telling it to do. You have an array of 50 characters allocated but only a few of them are overwritten with your user input. When you write the structure to file, you write the full 50 characters. As suggested in the answer from John Zwinck, you can accept to have those characters there and them not being legible, you can write a custom reader / writer that will take care of managing lengths read / written, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing these values to the file:

```
int fposition;
int fIdKey;
char ftitle[50];
char fgenre[50];
int fyear;
```

But you are displaying the whole file as characters.  That kind of works for `ftitle` and `fgenre` because they really are characters...though since you don't populate all 50 characters there are some ugly uninitialized characters shown as well.  That is easy to fix: just fill the unused characters (as well as the null terminator) with some known character (such as space) before writing to the file, or do not write the unused characters at all.  You can use `strlen()` to find the length of each string and `memset()` to set the unused characters to a well-known character which is printable.

Next, saving an `int` and reading it as text is problematic.  You need to decide on a single format.  Either you write as integers like now, and you read as integers (which means you need a special program to read the file), or you commit to writing only text to the file.

Easiest might be to only write text to the file.  You can use `fprintf()` for that, instead of `fwrite()`.  You can use `fprintf()` for the character arrays as well, it will automatically write only the "used" part of each string up to the null terminator, skipping all the "garbage" characters.